# How can i add First and Last page link in my laravel pagination

Tags: laravel-5

Right now i am using laravel 5.8 and i am using default pagination with the use of paginate() method for pagination.But i want First and Last page with this. So please help me if any buddy have demo code then please share in Answer section please.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#paginator-instance-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you first need to [export the views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view).

Then you can modify them to add a link to [`$results->lastPage()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#paginator-instance-methods).